# Issue with dates while reading a csv file in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, datetime, python-datetime

I am playing with time series but having a lot of troubles to align dates in Pandas. Ultimately I want to be able to join several time series (each in a separate csv file) but the join does not work due to a mismatch in the date index.

My main date index is created by the function fn_range_date() and has a format YYYY-MM-DD while most of the dates in the csv files are in the format DD/YY/YYYY (+ time stamp). I have tried with a parser straight in the read_csv but without success.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def fn_range_date():
   start = datetime.date(2015, 9, 21)
   end = datetime.date(2017, 9, 11)
   days = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start, end, freq="W-MON"))
   df = pd.DataFrame({'DateID': days})
   return df

ind = fn_range_date()
ind.set_index('DateID', inplace=True)

df1 = pd.pandas.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=0, header=None).T
df1.columns = ['DateID', 'Value']
df1.set_index(date, inplace=True)

result = ind.join(df1, how='outer')
print (result)
```

My csv file looks like this:

```
Date    21/09/2015 00:00    28/09/2015 00:00    05/10/2015 00:00    12/10/2015 00:00
Value   40,185  18,246  18,901  19,931
```

How to solve this? The date should ideally be in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to solve this issue. The csv file was in an awkward format so I have first transpose the file in order to read it properly:

```
def fn_read_csv(filename):
   pd.read_csv(filename).T.to_csv('temp_' + filename,header=False)
   parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
   df = pd.pandas.read_csv('temp_' + filename, parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser, index_col=0)
   df.columns = [filename.replace(".csv","")]
   df.index.rename('DateID', inplace=True)
   os.remove('temp_' + filename)
   return df
```